# Add expiry headers to off-server objects?

Tags: php, jquery

I just want to ask if it is possible to add expiry headers to the off-domain objects, for example, if I include jQuery from google CDN, can I add expiry header to it using htaccess or PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because you don't control the remote servers, which are the ones that will send the expiry header.

But why would you want to? Certainly for something like jQuery on CDN, it's not going to change in a hurry, and you would want to cache it, to make your pages appear as fast as possible. Using the CDN libraries means that a user who has visited *any site* that uses the CDN jQuery library will receive the library from cache.

Here's a good discussion of the advantages of using Google CDN for hosting jQuery: http://encosia.com/6953-reasons-why-i-still-let-google-host-jquery-for-me/